# Copying a shared folder that exceeds 255 chars in VmWare Workstation

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, vmware

I want to transfer files from the guest to the host, however the guest Windows OS complains about the file path being too long. Host is also Windows by the way.

Is there any other way I can copy the files instead?

Comment: This may sound obvious but - reduce the length of the path to less than 255 characters. That's all Windows supports.

Comment: @Appleoddity For my situation, I can't. I need the filenames to remain as they are.

Comment: The file names can remain as they are, but one or more folder names somewhere in the entire path has to be shortened. You can force this but you're going to have trouble. It's like forcing a square peg in to a round hole, it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'll have to rename too many directories, then. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a copying tool that supports using [*extended-length paths*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247#maxpath).  For example, [you should be able to use robocopy to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865863/how-to-move-folder-files-with-path-names-255-characters-in-windows-8-1).

I am not sure if it would work via shared folders, but you instead could mount the guest's disk on the host and use robocopy directly.